# How to initialize char 2d array quickly?

Tags: java, arrays, char

In C, I could initialize 2d char array using something like

```
 public static char hashTable[10][5] = {"", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
            "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};
```

I am wondering how to do this in Java?

Comment: Do you mean a 2d char array?

Comment: yes, I mean 2d array

Comment: You can use ‘\u0000’ or Character.MIN_VALUE for empty char

Comment: sounds right, ok

Comment: Quickly in what sense?  Do you mean the smallest number of source characters?  The quickest to write the source code?  (Not necessarily the same!)  The smallest runtime overhead ... when executed once?  Or when executed multiple times?

Comment: And by the say, that C code has problems with the typing. It is not allocated as a `char[10][5]`.  It is actually a 10 element array of `const char *` since you can't modify a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke `toCharArray()` on your `String` literals, the most similar construct I can think of is

```
public static char[][] hashTable = { 
        "".toCharArray(), "".toCharArray(), 
        "abc".toCharArray(), "def".toCharArray(),
        "ghi".toCharArray(), "jkl".toCharArray(), 
        "mno".toCharArray(), "pqrs".toCharArray(), 
        "tuv".toCharArray(), "wxyz".toCharArray() 
};
```

Comment: Shorter version of `"".toCharArray()` would be `{}`, but `"".toCharArray()` probably better shows the intent.

Comment: You should probably also address the change from `[10][5]` to `[][]`, especially the fact that none of them will arrays of length 5, and that result is a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: @Andreas Pretty sure the [C is too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027205/how-to-initialize-char-2d-array-quickly/53027272?noredirect=1#comment92956298_53027205).

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following,

```
public static char[][] arr = {{'a', 'd'},{'s','w','f'}};
```

arr[0] references the first array which is {‘a’, ‘d’} while arr[1] references the second

Comment: how to represent empty char?

Comment: What is an empty `char`?  Do you mean an empty string?  If yes, then `{}` ... in this context.

Comment: @AdamLee If you actually mean empty `char`, you don't really need one like in C since the subarrays in Java have differing lengths if you use this answer.

Comment: Even in C, a `'\000'` is not really "empty".